# How do I add options to Communication Preferences

Tags: fields, preferences

Is it possible to add to the Communication Preferences in contact profiles? At present we only have 'NO BULK EMAIL' (USER OPT OUT) we would like to create 'NO BULK EMAIL (ADMIN OPT OUT) or similar. Is this possible? We would rather not remove them from the various tags and groups as this is useful info for us. 
Thanks in advance.
William

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you can simply add a Communication Preference like you can add an option group as there is also quite some processing involved rather than 'just' a way to inform you about something. So if you would want that you would also have to influence the code. You can add a preferred communication method, but that is different because there is no processing related.

Answer (score 1):

We have quite a few communication preference fields, and use a combination of two approaches (which of course each have their own pros/cons...)
1) Word Replacements to change an existing Communications Preference field name, and 
2) A Custom Field Set for other communication preferences beyond what already exist.